# Como ordenar uma ListBox

Tags: c#

Tenho uma listBox e dois botões do lado, um pra mover pra cima e o outro para baixo o item selecionado. Porém, a lista está carregada pelo `DataSource` de uma tabela do banco, queria ordenar a posição dos itens da lista, porque depois de ordenar vou salvar esses itens em outra tabela.

Vi que tem o `moveNext`, mas ele não muda a posição, só muda a seleção.

```
 private void btnSobe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     bdsCliente.MoveFirst();
 }

 private void btnDesce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     bdsCliente.MoveLast();
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796109/how-to-move-item-in-listbox-up-and-down

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748949/move-up-move-down-buttons-for-listboxes-in-visual-studio

Comment: Isso é em WebForms ou Desktop? O problema do .NET WebForms, é que ele estimula o uso de POST para qualquer ação do usuário - mesmo que envolva interface.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ordenar a lista com Linq e depois atribuir a lista ordenada como data source do ListView novamente.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
private void btnOrdenaListView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Ordena a lista por um campo aleatório.
     var registrosOrdenados = listView.DataSource.OrderBy(x => x.Id);

     listView.DataSource = registrosOrdenados;
}
```